# How do I test this reducer correctly?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing

I am working on unit test for my reducer and I don't know what  I am doing wrong here. The error I am getting in the console is that Matcher error: received value must be a non-null object and received value is undefined.

Reducer

```
import uuid from "uuid/v4";
import { 
  ADD_TODO,
  REMOVE_TODO,
  TOGGLE_TODO,
  EDIT_TODO
} from "../constants/Actions";

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TODO:
      return [...state, { id: uuid(), task: action.task, completed: false }];
    case REMOVE_TODO:
      return state.filter(todo => todo.id !== action.id);
    case TOGGLE_TODO:
      return state.map(todo =>
          todo.id === action.id ? { ...todo, completed: !todo.completed } : todo
        );
    case EDIT_TODO:
      return state.map(todo =>
        todo.id === action.id ? { ...todo, task: action.task } : todo
      )
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default reducer;
```

And my test is.

```
import { useReducer } from "react";
import { act, renderHook } from "@testing-library/react-hooks";
import { reducer } from "../src/reducers/Todo";
import { ADD_TODO } from '../src/constants/Actions'

describe("Todo reducer tests", () => {
  it("Add Todo", () => {
    const { result } = renderHook(() => useReducer(reducer, []));
    const [state, dispatch] = result.current;

    act(() => {
      dispatch({ type: ADD_TODO })
    });

    expect(state).toMatchObject({
        id: 1,
        task: 'Hello',
        completed: true,
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: You have two asserts. Which one is failing? You're also dispatching a type that doesn't exist: `dispatch({ type: actions.type })`

Comment: The first one @AndyRay How can i fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to check [redux offical how to write test correctly](https://redux.js.org/recipes/writing-tests) 
this help me a lot and they explain for every stuff you need
here is my code where I use like redux show.

```
import reducer from './reducer';
import * as actionTypes from '../Actions/actionTypes';

describe('reducer CheclUp', () => {
    it('should return the initial state', () => {
        expect(reducer(undefined, {})).toEqual({
            favorite: [],
            SearchPlaces: [],
        });
    });

    it('should remove favorite and move it to SearchPlaces', () => {
        expect(reducer({
            favorite: [{Key: "1"}],
            SearchPlaces: [],
        }, { 
            type: actionTypes.REMOVE_FAVORITE,
            payload: "1"
         })).toEqual({
            favorite: [],
            SearchPlaces: [{Key: "1"}],
        });
    });

    it('should remove SearchPlaces and move it to favorite', () => {
        expect(reducer({
            favorite: [],
            SearchPlaces: [{Key: "1"}],
        }, { 
            type: actionTypes.ADD_EXISTED_TO_FAV,
            payload: "1"
         })).toEqual({
            favorite: [{Key: "1"}],
            SearchPlaces: [],
        });
    });
    it('should remove from SearchPlaces', () => {
        expect(reducer({
            favorite: [],
            SearchPlaces: [{Key: "1"}],
        }, { 
            type: actionTypes.REMOVE_SEARCHED_PLACE,
            payload: "1"
         })).toEqual({
            favorite: [],
            SearchPlaces: [],
        });
    });
    it('should add to SearchPlaces', () => {
        expect(reducer({
            favorite: [],
            SearchPlaces: [],
        }, { 
            type: actionTypes.ADD_SEARCHED_PLACE,
            payload: [{Key: "1"}]
         })).toEqual({
            favorite: [],
            SearchPlaces: [{Key: "1"}],
        });
    });
    it('should remove from SearchPlaces', () => {
        expect(reducer({
            favorite: [],
            SearchPlaces: [],
        }, { 
            type: actionTypes.ADD_FAVORITE,
            payload: [{Key: "1"}]
         })).toEqual({
            favorite: [{Key: "1"}],
            SearchPlaces: [],
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `state` starts off as `undefined` because you don't have a default state set. Your reducer hits the `default` case and returns `state`, which isn't set in your first reducer run. I recommend setting a default state in your reducer:

```
const reducer = (state = [], action) => {
```

You can also [pass in an initial state instead](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer):

```
const { result } = renderHook(() => useReducer(reducer, []));
```

Comment: I updated my questions test part.. I get now following error ...  @Andy Ray
expect(received).toMatchObject(expected)

    Expected: {"completed": true, "id": 1, "task": "Hello"}
    Received: []

      13 |     });
      14 |
    > 15 |     expect(state).toMatchObject({
         |                   ^
      16 |         id: 1,
      17 |         task: 'Hello',
      18 |         completed: true,

Comment: Yeah, I read it and it gives expect the array object but got an array

Comment: Yes, your reducer returns arrays, not objects

Comment: it("Add Todo", () => {
    const { result } = renderHook(() => useReducer(reducer, []));
    const [state, dispatch] = result.current;

    act(() => {
      dispatch({type: ADD_TODO })
    });

    expect(state).toMatchObject([]);
  });
});
 ?